# Handling somewhat complex JSON data with jQuery Templates

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-plugins, jquery-templates

I'm not a JS expert but I've been given a JSON model to display using jQuery, and have my hopes up for jQuery Templates. However all the documentation examples seem to be for simple 2-level arrays, and I can't translate these examples to the JSON I have. I'm not clear on whether I should be working with **jQuery.tmpl()**, or **{{each}}** or **{{tmpl}}** or **{{wrap}}** to iterate through this data.

I need to acquire the JSON below and display each "host" name followed by its "states" details (CPU, Disk, Mem.) Any hints on how to proceed are much appreciated.

```
{"health":64,
"hosts":[
        {
        "name":"Windows2000P",
        "states":[
            {"name":"CPU","link":"(html link)","bgcolor":"#CC99CC"},
            {"name":"Disk","link":"(html link)","bgcolor":"#CC99CC"},
            {"name":"Mem","link":"(html link)","bgcolor":"#CC99CC"}
            ]
        },
        {
        "name":"Windows2003",
        "states":[
            {"name":"CPU","link":"(html link)","bgcolor":"#98FB98"},
            {"name":"Disk","link":"(html link)","bgcolor":"#98FB98"},
            {"name":"Mem","link":"(html link)","bgcolor":"#F08080"}
            ]
        },
        {
        "name":"Windows7",
        "states":[
            {"name":"CPU","link":"(html link)","bgcolor":"#98FB98"},
            {"name":"Disk","link":"(html link)","bgcolor":"#98FB98"},
            {"name":"Mem","link":"(html link)","bgcolor":"#F08080"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of the kind of template you might use:

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <h2>${health}</h2>

  {{each hosts}}
  <h3>${name}</h3>

  <ul>
    {{each states}}
    <li style="background-color: ${bgcolor};"><a href="${link}">${name}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Dave! I believe you've gotten me on the right track -- I'm now looping over and displaying the JSON data. I really appreciate you taking the time to create an example for me.

Comment: @Dave Any idea how to do exactly what you are doing here but take it one step further and support data linking? I'm having a hard time finding documentation on how to data link a template using a complex object like this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks